# How can I use reduce to add indexValue of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```js
const numberArray = [2, 23, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const added = numberArray.reduce((sum, indexValue, index, numberArray) => { 

        if(index === 0) {
            console.log(`${index} : ${indexValue}`);
        }else{
            return sum += indexValue;
        }

    }, 0);

console.log(added);
```

Comment: what do you want to do ? Please clarify your issue or at least provide a wanted output sample.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to introduce your problem with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) should always return something, specifically a value that can be used in the reduction calculation.  Currently yours doesn't if `index === 0`.  The default return value is `undefined`, and once you perform math on `undefined` you get `NaN`.

Return a value.  For example, if you want to return `0`:

```js
const numberArray = [2, 23, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const added = numberArray.reduce((sum, indexValue, index, numberArray) => { 

        if(index === 0) {
            console.log(`${index} : ${indexValue}`);
            return 0; // <--- here
        }else{
            return sum += indexValue;
        }

    }, 0);

console.log(added);
```